# CodeIgniter фреймворк

Tags: codeigniter

Здравствуйте, сегодня у меня вопрос по `CodeIgniter`. Скачал файеморвк, пощупал, понравилось, и вот хотел бы какой-нибудь быстрый старт, типа мануала, или видео, или полезные ссылки на эту тему, или может даже совет, буду рад услышать. Я бы еще рад посмотреть сайты построенные на `CodeIgniter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все нужные ресурсы можно найти на [сайте проекта](http://www.codeigniter.com).

Answer (score 1):

Cкачай видео курсы Дмитрия Науменко - "PHP и CodeIgniter с Нуля"

Вот его [сайт](http://www.codeharmony.ru/)

Либо - "PHP Мастер - Как стать профессиональным PHP-программистом за 3 месяца"
автор - Александр Долгу

вообще, [он](http://www.google.ru/) тебе в помощь =)

Answer (score 1):

[Документация](http://cidocs.ru/)

[Допы](http://getsparks.org/)